# An example of how UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews works?

Tags: ios, core-animation

Apple's documentation describes `UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews` as:

> Lay out subviews at commit time so that they are animated along with
>   their parent.

Here is a sample of the code I'm interested in.  I wish to animate the `-layoutSubviews` of `detailView`; however, it doesn't seem to layout the subviews of `detailView`, so I'm not sure what effect it actually has.

```
    void (^animation) () = ^
    {
        [self.detailView setNeedsLayout];
        [self.detailView layoutIfNeeded];
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                     animations:^{
                         animation();
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your second animation to occurs from the current state of your first animation (whether it is finished or not) I recommend to use the UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews option when setting your second animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                 animations:^{
                     CGAffineTransform settingsTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.animatedView.frame.size.width, 0);
                        self.animatedView.transform = settingsTransform;
                 } 
completion:nil];
```